# Assembly Files: Difference between .a .s .asm

Tags: file, assembly, mips, file-type

In the MIPS simulator "QTSpim", three types of files are accepted:

- `.a`
- `.s`
- `.asm`

Is there a difference between those filetypes, and if yes, what is the difference?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Unix/Linux systems:

- `.a` is the usual extension for static libraries (aka Archives of multiple `.o` files, made with `ar(1)`).  Dynamic libraries, aka Shared Objects, use `.so`.
- `.s` is used for asm compiler output.  (`gcc -S foo.c` produces asm output, with a default filename of `foo.s`)
- **`.S` is used for hand-written asm source files**.  `gcc -c foo.S` runs it through the C preprocessor (so you can use `#include<>`, `#if`, `#define`, and C-style comments.)  Some C headers, like `asm/unistd.h` only have `#define`s, and so can be included in a .S to get definitions like `__NR_write` system call numbers, for example.

In x86, there are two separate versions of asm syntax: AT&T (used by Unix compilers like gcc), and Intel/NASM (with a couple dialects, like MASM vs. NASM itself).

`.S` is appropriate for asm in GNU `as` syntax, whether you use any C preprocessor features or not.

In x86, `.asm` is more often associated with Intel-syntax NASM/YASM, or MASM, source code.  Outside of x86, it's probably a good choice for asm source files that could be assembled by the platform-specific assembler, if it uses [different directives than GNU `as`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Pseudo-Ops.html).

The [glibc source tree uses `.S` for all asm source files](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=sysdeps).

---

People with a gcc background might put their MIPS asm into `.S` or `.s` files, while people with more NASM/YASM experience (or Windows), might go for `.asm`.

I'd recommend against `.s` files, because it's easy to accidentally overwrite with `gcc -S foo.c`.

Comment: .s is backend generated assembler. IOW it is assembler written by a compiler. The traditional Unix extension for actual handwritten assembler is .S (capital). Since most compilers don't generate textual assembler by default .S is better comparable to .asm.

Comment: In fact, .a is the name of a `ranlib` generated library/archive.  From what I remember 25 years ago, it actually meant "archive."